# Finding the Euler-Lagrange equation of a functional

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I have a question about finding the Euler-Lagrange equation. Suppose $\Omega$ is a bound domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. If $u$ is a critical point of the functional:
$$F(v)=\int_\Omega (\Delta v)^2$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian,
then for all smooth $v$
$$\tag{1}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}F(u+tv)\Big|_{t=0}=\int_\Omega \Delta u\Delta v
=\int_\Omega v \Delta^2 u +\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(\Delta u\frac{\partial v}{\partial\nu} -v\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}(\Delta u)\right).$$
To find Euler-Lagrange equation for which $u$ satisfies, we try to put all the derivatives to $u$; something like:
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}F(u+tv)\Big|_{t=0}=\int_\Omega v E_1(u)+\int_{\partial\Omega}v E_2(u)$$
and conclude that $u$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$E_1(u)=0\mbox{ in }\Omega~~\mbox{ and }~~E_2(u)=0\mbox{ on }\partial\Omega.$$
Therefore, I do not know how to deal the the first term in the last integral of $(1)$,
since it involves the normal derivative of $v$. I appreciate if someone could give me some ideas. Thank you very much.

Comment: FWIW: A minimum clearly corresponds to $\Delta v=0$.